# Where can I get a good vertical menu for asp.net mvc

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc

Anyone have any idea where I can get a good collapsible (and stay open when selected) vertical menu for an asp.net mvc project?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[Superfish](http://users.tpg.com.au/j_birch/plugins/superfish/)! Very flexible and you can easily set it up with asp.net mvc.

Answer (score 1):

Checkout the [10 best jquery menu plugins guide](http://www.ajaxline.com/10-best-jquery-menu-plugins)

My favorites?

- [jQuery iPod-style Drilldown Menu](http://www.filamentgroup.com/lab/jquery_ipod_style_drilldown_menu/)
- [jGlideMenu](http://www.sonicradish.com/labs/jGlideMenu/current/static_demo.html)

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried looking at the plugins at http://jquery.com/?

There are heaps and heaps of good menus etc there.

Answer (score -1):

Here's a great Asp.net iPod-style menu which I use for my clients. Uses jQuery and loads the sitemeap with Ajax. It doesn't have re-sizing problems, is permenenatly visible and always shows the current navigation level in the viewport, which makes it much more practical for real world projects.
http://dotnetipodmenu.com/