# How to create dynamic menu in asp.net mvc?

Tags: asp.net-mvc

How to create dynamic menu on views in asp.net mvc 2.0?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1489934/where-can-i-get-a-good-vertical-menu-for-asp-net-mvc

Answer (score 2):

Could you be a bit more spesific maybe?

If it's just a list of links it's easy enough, you just loop trough them an output a link with the Html.Action helper.

Something like:

```
<div class="menu">
<% // From the Controller we got the following list of links as a IEnumerable<String> { "Home", "About" } put in Model.
foreach(var lAddr in Model) { %>
    <%= Html.Action(lAddr, lAddr) %><br />
<% } %>
</div>
```

This should hender something like (if in an Controller named Home):

```
<a href="/Home/Home">Home</a><br /><a href="/Home/About">About</a>
```

Answer (score 0):

Use JQuery menu.

http://p.sohei.org/stuff/jquery/menu/demo/demo.html

Use controller to build ViewData for menu. Build the Menu in view by iterating over the ViewData for Menu.